How to Define a JSPromise Function in Dart Using dart:js_interop? in flutter sdk >= 3.3.0
I'm trying to define a JSPromise function in Dart to interoperate with a JavaScript class. Despite multiple attempts, I haven't been able to get it working. Here’s the Dart code I'm working with:
@JS("MyClass")
extension type MyClass._(JSObject _) implements Object {
  external MyClass();
  external set myObject(JSFunction args);
  external set myObjectAsync(JSPromise<MyObject> args);
}


I'm not sure how to properly define the JSPromise function. How can I correctly define a function that handles JavaScript Promises in Dart?

I found the solution. We need to define the method using JSFunction:
@JS("MyClass")
extension type MyClass._(JSObject _) implements Object {
  external MyClass();
  external set myObject(JSFunction args);
  external set myObjectAsync(JSFunction args);
}


To set the method and handle asynchronous calls, use JSPromise
Future<MyJsObject> handleRequest(JSString args) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  // Additional processing...
  return myJsObject;
}

JSPromise<MyJsObject> onRequest(JSString args) {
  final promise = handleRequest(args).toJS;
  return promise;
}

final myClass = MyClass();
myClass.myObjectAsync = onRequest.toJS;

Then, in JavaScript, you can use the method asynchronously:
async function fetchMyObject(args) {
  let myObject = await myObjectAsync(args);
  // Use myObject as needed
}

